# How to deep merge two multi-root tree structure made of array and hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

I have a nested structure made of `Hash`es and `Array`s that we can call multi-root nth-ary Tree.

I'm representing this structure

Here's an example:

```
[:o, {
  a: :b,
  c: [:d, :e, { f: { h: :i, l: [:m, :n] } }]
}]
```

That represents can be represented with this schema:

```
o        a          c
        /          /|\
       b          d e f
                      /\
                     h  l
                    /  / \
                   i  m   n
```

I want to deep merge it with another similar structure. Here's an example:

```
[:z, {
  o: :s,
  c: [:f, { d: :w }]
}]

z      o      c
       |     / \
       s    f   d
                 \
                  w
```

The resulting tree should be something like this:

```
[:z, {
    a: :b,
    c: [:e, { f: { h: :i, l: [:m, :n] }, d: :w }],
    o: :s
 }]


z       a           c           o
        |          /|\          |
        b         e f d         s
                   /|  \
                  h l   w
                  | |\
                  i m n
```

How can I do this?

I started with this, but I got struck:

```
def deep_merge(a, b)
  case a
  when Hash
    case b
    when Hash
      merge_hashes(a, b)
    when Array
      merge_array_hash(b, a)
    else
      [b, a]
    end
  when Array
    case b
    when Array
      merge_arrays(a, b)
    when Hash
      merge_array_hash(a, b)
    else
      [b] + a
    end
  else
    case b
    when Hash
      [a, b]
    when Array
      [a] + b
    else
      a == b ? a : [a, b]
    end
  end
end

# EXAMPLES:
# merge_array_hash([:a, :b], { f: :w })
# => [:a, :b, { f: :w }]
# merge_array_hash([:a, :b, { c: :d }], { f: :w })
# => [:a, :b, { c: :d, f: :w }]
def merge_array_hash(a, b)
  if a.last.is_a? Hash
    a[0...-1] + [merge_hashes(a.last, b)]
  else
    a + [b]
  end
end

# EXAMPLES:
# merge_hashes({ a: :b }, { c: :d })
# => { a: :b, c: :d }
# merge_hashes({ a: :b }, { d: e, a: :f })
# => { a: [:b, :f], d: :e }
def merge_hashes(a, b)
  a.deep_merge(b) do |_, this_val, other_val|
    deep_merge(this_val, other_val)
  end
end

# EXAMPLES:
# merge_arrays([:a, :b], [:c])
# => [:a, :b, :c]
# merge_arrays([:a, :b { c: :d }], [:f, { c: :e }])
# => [:a, :b, :f, { c: [:d, :e] }]
# merge_arrays([:a, :b { c: :d }], [:f, { c: :e }])
# => [:a, :b, :f, { c: [:d, :e] }]
def merge_arrays(a, b)
  keys = merge_array_keys(a, b)
  hashes = merge_hashes(a.last.is_a?(Hash) ? a.last : {}, b.last.is_a?(Hash) ? a.last : {})
  hashes.empty? keys : (keys + [hashes])
end

# EXAMPLES:
# merge_array_keys([:a, :b], [:f])
# => [:a, :b, :f]
# merge_array_keys([:a, :b { c: :d }], [:f, { c: :e }])
# => [:a, :b, :f]
def merge_array_keys(a, b)
  a.reject { |e| e.is_a?(Hash) } + b.reject { |e| e.is_a?(Hash) }
end
```

As you can see, my solution was a little bit too complex, I think there's a more intelligent way, but I can't find it. Any ideas?

NB: the key order doesn't metter

NB: If there is an Array that contains an Hash, the hash must be the last item of the array

NB: I'm not interested in performances, it could be also very slow for big trees

NB: If you have better ideas to represent this structure in a more intelligent way, for me is ok!

Comment: Break it up into smaller methods that is easier to relate to.

Comment: @Albin ok, wait editing...

Comment: Break it up into smaller methods. Like `merge_hash_with_hash`, `merge_hash_with_array` and so on.

Comment: Why this question is unclear? I just want to deep merge a multi-tree structure, why should it be closed?
@Albin I improved a bit the code

Comment: I think the problem is that your question is to high level. It's more of a "fix my code"-kind of problem which SO people don't really like. You've to point us to a specific problem.

Comment: @Oleander The problem is that I can't conclude my code at all, since my code is becoming very complex. My question is more like: `Is there a better way to merge this kind of data structure?` than `Please make my horrible code work`

Comment: Shouldn't `merge_array_hash` raise an error? I mean, how can you merge `[1,2,3]` with `{a: b, c: d}`? Could you maybe add some examples above each merge method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104387/discussion-between-oleander-and-progm).

Comment: @Oleander No, that is not the problem. The OP invited the problem by themselves.

Comment: @sawa I was taking about the problem is general. How would such a merge look?

Comment: @Oleander I am mentioning your earlier comment.

Comment: @ProGM Sorry for being such a nitpicker, but simplify your examples. You only need to show how to merge `[c]` with `{a: b}` and `{a: b}` with `[c]` and so forth.

Comment: `{ a: :b }` merged with `[:c]` is: `[:c, {a: :b}]`

Comment: Did you found a way to do it ?!

Comment: @PandaCool yep: https://gist.github.com/ProGM/79e72876dbbcbbd79a2beec893c4f6e8