# Flat hash to json hash tree with a hierarchy

Tags: ruby, json, algorithm, hash, tree

I have a hash with my hierarchy like `['country', 'city', 'street', ...]`
 who's the head to last son of my tree.

My data look like

```
{"country": "france", "city": "paris", "street": "champs elysee"},
{"country": "france", "city": "Lyon", "street": "lyon street"},
{"country": "italy", "city": "rome", "street": "rome street1"},
...
```

I would like to transform this into a tree like

```
[
  {
    "france" => [
      {
         "paris" => {"champs elysee" => [...]},
         "lyon" => {"lyon street1" => [...]}
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "italy" => [
      {
         "rome" => {"rome street 1" => [...]},
         ...
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

And be able to change my hierarchy

I tried many things but i didn't find any solution.. I think to didn't have the right approach.

EDIT :

This is my code (Not working at all) but it's the idea.

```
require 'json'

@hierarchie = ["country", "city", "street"]

f = File.read("./data.json")
@ret = JSON.parse(f)

@tree = []
def render_as_tree
    @ret.each do |datum|
         ptr = @tree
         @hierarchie.each do |h|
             if ptr.empty?
                 ptr << {datum[h] => []}
             end
             obj = ptr.detect {|d| datum[h]}
             ptr = obj[ datum[h] ]
         end
    end
    return @tree
end

puts render_as_tree()
```

This code is a small exemple of my code. My code is not with country/city/street but it's better for understanding and explanation.

The `...` means the number of child could change dynamicly. For this exemple i could have `country/city/district/street/house/...` or just `country/city` so my last data need to be the flat data.

Comment: This part of your result doesn't make sense: `{[ {"champs elysee"} => [...] ]},`. First, the outer `{}` are invalid, and second, what does the `...` signify?

Comment: in the hierarchy i put `...` also, because street could have many number for exemple, and the tree could have a different depth so the `...` could be another `{"???" => [] }`

Comment: Are the input hashes' keys strictly ordered? (If not we need a list of all possible keys to know the correct order for the hierarchy.) And what should the last (leaf) elements look like? An empty array?

Comment: No, i get the input hash key with a `detect` and the last key need to be my hash.

Comment: If the input hashes' keys aren't ordered then this problem cannot be solved without a list of all possible keys in the correct order.

Comment: i update with the code and the `...` explanation

Comment: @PandaCool, `{[ {"rome street 1"} => [...] ]}` this is invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ProGM i found the solution !

[How to deep merge two multi-root tree structure made of array and hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598461/how-to-deep-merge-two-multi-root-tree-structure-made-of-array-and-hashes?noredirect=1#comment64274056_35598461)

```
class Tree
  attr_reader :data

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end

  def +(other)
    Tree.new(deep_merge(@data, other.is_a?(Tree) ? other.data : other))
  end

  delegate :empty?, to: :data

  def replace(other)
    @data.replace(other.data)
  end

  def root
    level(0)
  end

  def levels
    output = []
    i = -1
    while i += 1
      current_level = level(i)
      break if current_level.all?(&:nil?)
      output << current_level
    end
    output
  end

  def level(level_number)
    all_elements_at_level(@data, level_number)
  end

  private

  def deep_merge(a, b)
    case a
    when Hash
      return merge_hashes(a, b) if b.is_a?(Hash)
      return merge_array_hash(b, a) if b.is_a?(Array)
      [b, a]
    when Array
      return merge_arrays(a, b) if b.is_a?(Array)
      return merge_array_hash(a, b) if b.is_a?(Hash)
      [b] + a
    else
      return [a, b] if b.is_a?(Hash)
      return [a] + b if b.is_a?(Array)
      a == b ? a : [a, b]
    end
  end

  def merge_array_hash(a, b)
    if a.last.is_a? Hash
      a[0...-1] + [merge_hashes(a.last, b)]
    else
      a + [b]
    end
  end

  def merge_hashes(a, b)
    a.deep_merge(b) do |_, this_val, other_val|
      deep_merge(this_val, other_val)
    end
  end

  def merge_arrays(a, b)
    keys = merge_array_keys(a, b)
    hashes = merge_hashes(a.last.is_a?(Hash) ? a.last : {}, b.last.is_a?(Hash) ? b.last : {})
    if hashes.empty?
      keys
    else
      (keys - hashes.keys) + [hashes]
    end
  end

  def merge_array_keys(a, b)
    (a.reject { |e| e.is_a?(Hash) } + b.reject { |e| e.is_a?(Hash) }).uniq
  end

  def all_elements_at_level(data, level_number)
    return ground_level(data) if level_number == 0
    case data
    when Hash
      data.map { |_, v| all_elements_at_level(v, level_number - 1) }
    when Array
      data.map { |e| all_elements_at_level(e, level_number) }.flatten
    end
  end

  def ground_level(data)
    case data
    when Hash
      data.keys
    when Array
      data.map { |e| all_elements_at_level(e, 0) }.flatten
    else
      data
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `inject` or `each_with_object` to walk through your data

```
data = [
  {"country": "france", "city": "paris", "street": "champs elysee"},
  {"country": "france", "city": "Lyon", "street": "lyon street"},
  {"country": "italy", "city": "rome", "street": "rome street1"},
]

hierarchy = data.each_with_object({}) do |row, hsh|
  country = row[:country]
  city = row[:city]
  street = row[:street]
  hsh[country] ||= {}
  hsh[country][city] ||= {}
  hsh[country][city][street] ||= []
  hsh[country][city][street] << "?" # put here anything you need
end

p hierarchy
#=> {"france"=>{"paris"=>{"champs elysee"=>["?"]}, "Lyon"=>{"lyon street"=>["?"]}}, "italy"=>{"rome"=>{"rome street1"=>["?"]}}}
```

upd:

```
def tree(data, hierarchy)
  data.each_with_object({}) do |row, hsh|
    node = hsh
    hierarchy.each do |level|
      val = row[level]
      node[val] ||= {}
      node = node[val]
    end
  end
end

tree(data, [:country, :city])
#=> {"france"=>{"paris"=>{}, "Lyon"=>{}}, "italy"=>{"rome"=>{}}}
tree(data, [:country, :city, :street])
#=> {"france"=>{"paris"=>{"champs elysee"=>{}}, "Lyon"=>{"lyon street"=>{}}}, "italy"=>{"rome"=>{"rome street1"=>{}}}}
```

Comment: I had something like that, put i need by changing my hierarchy to get my tree change. i can't add another `hsh[country][city][street][..]`

Comment: @PandaCool, is that something you meant?

Comment: i just found that https://gist.github.com/awesome/3842062 it's close of what i need

Comment: It should be noted that you are returning nested hashes, which isn't quite what the OP wanted, but it's a definite improvement. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [{"country": "france", "city": "paris", "street": "champs elysee"},
       {"country": "france", "city": "lyon",  "street": "rue mandelot"},
       {"country": "italy", "city": "rome", "street": "via del corso"},
       {"country": "france", "city": "paris", "street": "rue montorgueil"}]

arr.each_with_object({}) {|g,h| ((h[g[:country]] ||={})[g[:city]] ||={})[g[:street]]=['x']}
  #=> {"france"=>{"paris"=>{"champs elysee"=>["x"], "rue montorgueil"=>["x"]},
  #               "lyon"=>{"rue mandelot"=>["x"]}},
  #    "italy"=>{"rome"=>{"via del corso"=>["x"]}}}
```

@fl00r and I have both returned an object comprised of nested hashes, rather than the alternating hashes and arrays specified in the question. Since each of the  arrays contain a single hash, they serve no purpose.

Answer (score -1):

```
require "json"

data = %|[{"country": "france", "city": "paris", "street": "champs elysee"},{"country": "france", "city": "Lyon", "street": "lyon street"},{"country": "italy", "city": "rome", "street": "rome street1"}]|

parsed = JSON.parse(data)

final = {}

parsed.each {
    |h|

    if final.has_key? h["country"]
        if final[h["country"]].key? h["city"]
            final[h["country"]][h["city"]].push h["street"]
        else
            final[h["country"]][h["city"]] = [ h["street"]]
        end
    else
        final[h["country"]] = {h["city"] => [ h["street"] ]}
    end
}

p final
```